# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library MetropolisULiveTile200.bpl

Tags: indy, delphi-xe6

Today I start getting this message when I open Delphi XE6.

> The procedure entry point @Idstackwindows@TidStackWindows@NetworkToHost$qqrj could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\bin\MetropolisULiveTile200.bpl.

I answered Yes to "Do you want to load it next time".

When I look in the folder I see that the `MetropolisULiveTile200.bpl` is in the folder.

I haven't installed anything new since 9/24/2020, when I installed the latest version of Indy. I have used Delphi XE6 every day since I upgraded.

It looks like any program I have are building and compiling without any errors.

I search the internet, but was not able to find any with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is documented in Indy's [installation notes](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx):

> In D/CB/RAD XE3+, Embarcadero's Metropolis UI LiveTile framework is compiled against the Indy 10 packages that ship with the IDE.  **Installing a new version of Indy will render LiveTiles unusable, as it will not be able to load the Indy packages anymore**, and LiveTiles cannot be recompiled by end users.  If you need to use LiveTiles then you will need to maintain the original Indy 10 packages for use in LiveTile projects.  You can use a separate installation of Indy 10 for non-LiveTile projects.  This has not been addressed by Embarcadero yet so Indy 10 upgrades and LiveTiles can co-exist.

If you were not getting this error between 9/24 and today, and now you are, then you probably opened a project today that has a dependency on (or at least enables) the LiveTile package, whereas projects you worked on earlier do not.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I'm not using LiveTiles for anything. When starting Delphi and it ask if I want to load it next time I will just answer no and I should be fine.